# Flutter imageCache.clear(); error messages

Tags: flutter

How do I put `imageCache.clear();` into my Flutter app? Five of my six images are loading but one refusing to load. I tried `flutter clean` and restarting Android Studio. When I do this at the top of the program:

```java
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
imageCache.clear();
```

I get this error message:

```
lib/main.dart:2:19: Error: Expected a function body or '=>'.
Try adding {}.
imageCache.clear();
```

I tried this

```
imageCache.clear() {}
```

but that got a different error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably put the function in the wrong place.

You can put in the `initState`

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    imageCache.clear();
}
```

or wherever a function should be not where a widget should be.